# How to Creat XML file like this using XML document?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

Basically i want to add my custom attributes with the default text view in android by Create XML file like this How can i Create my own XML Document like this ??
like

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView16"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"`enter code here`
android:text="TextView"
customfontdemo:fontName="Anything"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="163dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="166dp" />
```

so here is my custom attribute #`fontName` i want to add my custom attribute in Default UI components how can i do this ?? 
and read it in the .kt file

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and tell us what you tried. What are you doing? What programming language is this - add the relevant tag! Add the relevant code as well! For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can't add custom attributes to already defined views. you must first create a custom view that extends the `TextView` and then define attributes for your custom view

Comment: any other way it is very compulsory for me to do this things @nariman

Comment: You can achieve this thing by DataBinding with custom BindingAdaptors also.
ex. "https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to be able to use custom attributes on existing views.

In order to do that you will need to "hijack" the inflation process. 
The way you achieve that is by implementing a custom LayoutInflator.factory or factory2 if you target api 11+(Side note: The android team needs to learn how to name things)

the factory is an interface that contains a function

```
View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

Here's the full interface taken from the source code

```
 public interface Factory2 extends Factory {
    /**
     * Version of {@link #onCreateView(String, Context, AttributeSet)}
     * that also supplies the parent that the view created view will be
     * placed in.
     *
     * @param parent The parent that the created view will be placed
     * in; <em>note that this may be null</em>.
     * @param name Tag name to be inflated.
     * @param context The context the view is being created in.
     * @param attrs Inflation attributes as specified in XML file.
     *
     * @return View Newly created view. Return null for the default
     *         behavior.
     */
    public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs);
}
```

Look at this [tutorial](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/app-development-how-to-get-the-right-layoutinflater/) to help you implement the factory.
Once you have implemented the factory you can replace your

Activity's

```
setContentView(View)
```

Fragment/simple inflation types

```
onCreateView()
```

Comment: yeah you understand my question perfectly ! i'm stucking here how to implement your answer

Comment: Take a look at the attached link it supposed to give you some insight. If my answer helped you don't forget to upvote and approve